# Disappearing Text on webform

Tags: css, forms, text, formatting

One of my websites is having an issue with text disappearing and reappearing. Here is the url. If anyone knows a fix for it please let me know!

When using Chrome and you refresh there is a header at the top under Conway that should say Trucking Application and then in the blue area there should be text that says 'Fill out your application below to get in touch with a representative from Con-way Truckload!'

Then Each Yellow Section should also have text in them!

https://www.gettruckerjobs.com/conway/form

**UPDATE**

I included

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Oswald2';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/oswald/v8/-g5pDUSRgvxvOl5u-a_WHw.woff) format('woff');
}
```

The headers stated are still not showing working as expected. This is happening both on mac and windows but on a windows computer next to me I can't get the error to happen, Although if the headers show up when I load the page if I refresh then they disappear.

Comment: On first look I am not seeing any problems with text. Please be more specific: what is disappearing? Under what circumstances are you seeing the issue? What have you tried already?

Comment: When using Chrome and you refresh there is a header at the top under Conway that should say Trucking Application and then in the blue area there should be text that says 'Fill out your application below to get in touch with a representative from Con-way Truckload!'

Comment: Then Each Yellow Section should also have text in them!

Comment: Webfonts, right? Those are a problem in Chrome. See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002220/webfonts-not-rendering-with-mathjax), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929610/font-face-wont-load-when-visiting-the-site-for-the-first-time-must-refresh-re), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21942968/font-awesome-icons-disappear-after-refresh-in-chrome/22068538#22068538) etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Font awesome icon showing as square in chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805978/font-awesome-icon-showing-as-square-in-chrome)

Comment: Tried this but no luck. There is no icon showing up though there is supposed to be text but nothing shows up whatsoever. Sometimes it shows up just fine other times none of the headers show up

Comment: Looks like a potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984543/google-chrome-bug-website-not-displaying-text?

Answer (score 0):

Google fonts do not provide all required font types and they cause many errors in various browsers. Use other service and download your fonts, such as: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/oswald